# awk to extract the data between Dates

Tags: awk

Would like  to extract the line items,  if the dates between 5th Apr to 10th Apr from second field ($2) . Having many gun zip files into that directory.

Inputs.gz

```
Des1,DATE,Des1,Des2,Des3
ab,01-APR-15,10,0,4
ab,04-APR-15,25,0,12
ab,05-APR-15,40,0,6
ab,07-APR-15,55,0,6
ab,10-APR-15,70,0,1
ab,11-APR-15,85,0,1
```

I have tried below command and in-complete

```
zcat Inputs*.gz | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} { if ( (substr($2,1,2) >=5) && (substr($2,1,2) <=10) ) print $0 }'  > Output.txt
```

Expected Output

```
ab,05-APR-15,40,0,6
ab,07-APR-15,55,0,6
ab,10-APR-15,70,0,1
```

Please suggest ...

Comment: why not use AWK to extract lines between two separators, something like this `awk '/StartPattern/,/EndPattern/'` , in your case `awk '/05-APR-15/,/10-APR-15/'`

Comment: Thanks vlp for the inputs, it will fail if some the files not having 05-APR-15 but begins with 07-APR-15 and ends with 10-APR-15

Comment: @vlp you should never use range expressions as they make the solution for trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions if your requirements change in the slightest. Just use a flag. AVN - are your real dates always in one month of one year (e.g. April 2015) and you never have say `29-MAR-15...03-APR-15`?

Comment: Ed Morton, files are having many months of one year dates like 01-JAN-15 and 29-MAR-15 ..

Comment: When replying to someone specifically, use an `@` symbol in front of their id (e.g. `@EdMorton`) so they are notified that you are doing so otherwise they'll never know unless they just happen to revisit your question some time. So, the example you have posted doesn't reflect your actual input file and the answer you got won't work on your real input file so why did you select is as the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F",|-" '$2 >= 5 && $2 <= 10'
```

It adds the date delimiter to the `FS` using the `-F` flag.  To ensure that it's `APR` of 2015, you could separately add tests like:

```
awk -F",|-" '$2 >= 5 && $2 <= 10 && $3=="APR" && $4==15'
```

While this makes the date easy to parse up front, if you want to print it out again, you'll need to reconstruct it with something like `_date = $2 "-" $3 "-" $4`.  And if you need to manipulate the data in general, you'd want to add back in the `BEGIN {OFS=","}` part.

The field numbering I used assumes there are no "-" delimiters in the first field.

I get the following output:

```
ab,05-APR-15,40,0,6
ab,07-APR-15,55,0,6
ab,10-APR-15,70,0,1
```

If you have a whole mess of dates and you really only care about the one in the 2nd field via comma delimiters, you could use split like:

```
awk -F"," '{ split($2, darr, "-") } darr[1] >= 5 && darr[1] <= 10 && darr[2]=="APR" && darr[3]==15'
```

which is like saying:

- for every line, parse the 2nd field into the `darr` array using the `-` delimiter
- for every line, if the logic `darr[1] >= 5 && darr[1] <= 10 && darr[2]=="APR" && darr[3]==15` is true print the whole line.

Comment: Thanks a lot n0741337 for good support, I have accepted and up-voted the answer !!!

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution by using regular expression

```
awk  -F',' '$2 ~ /([0][5-9]|10)-APR-15/{ print $0  }' txt
```

- `-F` Field separator.
- `$2` second field
- `~` match regular expression
- '/([0][5-9]|10)-APR-15/` reguler expression to match 05 to 09 or 10
  APR-15

Using internal field separator

```
awk   'BEGIN{ FS="," } $2 ~ /([0][5-9]|10)-APR-15/{ print $0  }' txt
```

using explicate date number declarations

```
awk   'BEGIN{ FS="," } $2 ~ /(05|06|07|08|09|10)-APR-15/{ print $0  }' txt
```